# CURL Issue. PHP script not running on call

Tags: php, linux, apache, curl

I'm looking for any help debugging what could be preventing my php code from running when I CURL the page containing the script.

I am making this call from one PHP script:

```
$ch = curl_init($this->curl_address . $querystring);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

To this script: (the script actually does stuff, but it wasn't running, so I broke it down to this so that I would have evidence that it does not run, this is what is currently there, and there is no output in the log)

```
error_log("got here");
```

On my test server (a Mac), the CURL'd script runs (I get output in the log), but on my production server it fails. In both cases one script on the server is calling another.

The production server is a Linux VPS running (I believe) CentOS.

I don't know what issues I should be looking for on the production server. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: do you have curl installed on your server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I meant to update this question over the weekend when I finally figured out the problem. The production server was serving over HTTPS, while the test server was not. The issue I was having was because the server wasn't authenticating over cURL.

Comment: So you unpicked my answer because you found something unrelated to the answer? I gave the correct answer to what you asked and now you changed it. Downvoting your question then.

Answer (score 1):

In your script hosted in the server, use a `function_exists('curl_init');` to check whether **cURL** is installed or not. This function will return  a boolean **true** if the function exists, **false** otherwise.

If it returns **false**, you have to install **cURL** in the server.

You can also use a `phpinfo();` call, if you want detailed information about your PHP setup.

Comment: Hi Mario,  

Ok, I've run function_exists('curl_init'), and I get true returned. I checked out phpinfo, and the curl details are pretty slim in comparison to my test server. It only lists two lines:  

cURL support  enabled  
cURL Information  libcurl/7.21.4 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5  


The cURL response still returns false, and the error is not logged.  


Any thoughts?

Comment: Most likely that cURL is failing itself then. Try doing a `var_dump(curl_init());` and post its results.
If the result is something like “Resource #x” then cURL should be working fine and the issue is somewhere else.